# Fullcalendar ResourceDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there a way to see the "allDay" events in the "resourceDay" view in the jarnok's fullcalendar fork ?
Because now, I can see all the events that "pass" the day but not the events define at a day with the attribute "allDay" to true.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you had a look over here http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/ ?

Comment: @prakash2089 Yes and I havn't find what I want. I search a way to show "allday" events like in the classic "agendaWeek" view.

Comment: me too using jarno kurlin resoureViewCalendar, but my scenario didn't have any allDay events. Did u tried **allDay: true** in your json data, if so what error did u got?

Comment: I have it in my config and the allday events in agendaWeek view works. I think that's not a configuration problem but maybe someone found a "proper" solution to build it.

Comment: may be, you can mail Jarno Kurlin (jarno@kirottu.net) or create an issue in Github (https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar/issues?state=open) regrading this, then you will get an idea about this...